# Not able to find ToothPickRule class in 3.0.2 version

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, sdk, toothpick-di

I updated the `toothpick` sdk version to `3.0.2` from `1.1.3`. After updating, not able to find `ToothPickRule` class under testing package in `toothpick`. Which is causing test cases to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following dependency:

```
testImplementation 'com.github.stephanenicolas.toothpick:toothpick-testing-junit4:3.0.2'
```

it contains `ToothPickRule`.

The current version of ToothPick is 3.1.0 so you may want to update to it as well.